# Vue app not loading. What could be the problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

There are two versions of the site - DEV and PROD
Everything works fine on the DEV website, the application is loading
On the PROD website, it is completely absent, that is, there is simply nothing in id=visitor_app. the paths to the files are correct, the scripts are on those paths, but the application is still missing

this is the DEV version of the site

[image]

this is the PROD version of the site

[image]

I checked the paths to the files, they are correct on both versions of the site

Comment: How are you serving the PROD version?

Comment: any useful information in the console

Comment: there is nothing in the console

Comment: couple of questions: How is prod version is built and deployed? Can you verify if there is any version mismatch for any dependency package in package-lock.json?